# Cofibration and homotopy equivalence imply deformation retract?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Theorem 8 of Strom's *Notes on Cofibrations II* we have these conditions on a map for a lift to exist.

[image: Theorem 8 of Notes on Cofibrations II]

He references his *Notes on Cofibrations* Theorem 3 for the proof however the assumptions have changed. In Theorem 8, $i : X \rightarrow A$ is a cofibration, closed inclusion, and homotopy equivalence for $(ii)\implies (i)$. In Theorem 3 $i$ is a deformation retract and there exists a $\phi : X \rightarrow I$ such that $\phi^{-1}(0)=A$.

[image: Theorem 3 of Notes on Cofibrations]

Do the assumptions in Theorem 8 imply the assumptions in Theorem 3 or am I missing something?

Thanks :)

Comment: It would greatly help to understand your question if you could write out explicitly what you mean by "the assumptions in Theorem 8" and by "the assumptions in Theorem 3". Both of those theorems are complicated statements, and it's not clear what you are picking out of each of them and calling "the assumptions".

Comment: See Hatcher Corollary 0.20 on pg.16.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

I'll make sure I make my questions clear in the future.